# FileWatcher on Private Folder

Tags: c#

I have a windows service that listens on a folder on a server for newly added files. Once a new file is added then the services executes a method to carry out a specific function. I don't want the watched folder to be viewable or editable by users' that log in to the server. I would like for another program to c# .exe to be the only app that is able to view and add files. Is it possible to hide a folder away from users but make it available to an application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. This a server permissions issue and you'll probably get a better response from ServerFault.

Comment: The OP's folder is a local folder on the server - the same permissions apply whether it is a server or a local desktop folder.

Comment: @Raj_More, I should drop the 'server' reference. It's a straight permissions issue and still not programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this:

1. Create a Domain Account MyDomain/MyAccount (or have your Domain Admin create one for you)
2. Change permissions on your folder so that only the Domain Account MyDomain/MyAccount has permissions to the folder. Again, if you are unsure of how to do this, ask your Domain Admin to do this for you.
3. Right click the folder in Windows Explorer and mark the checkbox for HIDDEN property.
4. Change the Windows Service to run under MyDomain/MyAccount
5. Stop and restart the Windows Service.

Comment: Hiding the folder does not make it inaccessible, you just need to know where it is. You'd need to *remove* the permissions for everyone else to ensure it was only accessible to the application. You'd then also need to make sure you set the appropriate credentials on the service entry to make sure it was correct for folder. You would also need to make sure that the selected uid has appropriate permissions for any other aspects of the system that are not default.

Comment: @Lazarus, You're correct on that. That's why my step #2 is to change permissions,  and then step #3 is to hide it.

Comment: @Raj_More, good point. Not sure how I missed that, not enough caffeine today.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions in Windows are assigned to users, not applications. You can't grant exclusive access to an application, only to accounts or groups. There are various workarounds that may be of help:

- Grant permissions only to the service account and the user of the application (if it's a batch). If the application is used by multiple users, you should put all of them in a group and grant rights to the group.
- Place the folder in the AppData folder used by all applications to store data. While the folder is visible, users rarely access this folder. You can get the  AppData folder using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)`
- You can have the service application grant rights to the folder when it starts and revoke them when it finishes. You can't guarantee that an administrator won't just terminate the service, leaving the folder accessible to all.

What are you trying to do? There may be ways to accomplish it without granting permissions to an application.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the most appropriate for me:

•Place the folder in the AppData folder used by all applications to store data. While the folder is visible, users rarely access this folder. You can get the AppData folder using Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData)